# Putting TOC and LOF on the same page (PDF)

Tags: xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I tried several things to have my TOC and LOF on the same page in my PDF (xsltproc with fop), but none of them succeeded. Last thing I tried was tweaking force.page.count and initial.page.number as described here: http://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/docbook-apps/201202/msg00117.html though it does not work. I still get TOC and LOF on two different pages (but no empty verso page between them at least).

I also tried this, as it seems to describe exactly my problem, but also with no success: http://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/docbook-apps/200406/msg00218.html  Nothing changed at all when using the modified chapter-template in my own stylesheet (and given the fact that this answer is from 2004 it's likely to be outdated).